# VSTO Outlook: AddToSelection(mailItem) does not work

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

[image]
I have written an Outlook-VSTO-Add-In in VB to solve the issue that in Quick search results, Outlook does not tell you in which folder a found item lives.
My Add-In adds two items to the explorer's context menu:

1. `Name of containing folder` to display the name of the parent folder of the selected item
2. `Goto containing folder`    to change the current folder to the selected item's parent folder

This works all as desired.

Now, I'd like to extend the functionality of 2. so that when Outlook changes to the item's parent folder the item is automatically selected.

`myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem)` should do the thing, but unfortunately the adding operation fails; the selection count `myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count` is not changed. Any help would be much appreciated.

My environment:

- Windows 10
- Outlook für Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21296) 64 Bit
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.3
- Full project (as *.sln) is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Traveler4/WhatFolder2)

Code extract:

> ```
> Public Sub GetButtonID(control As Office.IRibbonControl)
>     Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
>
>     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Count: " & CStr(myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count))
>     If myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
>
>         Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem
>         mailItem = DirectCast(myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1), Outlook.MailItem)
>         Select Case control.Id
>             Case "FolderDisplay"
>                 Dim messageBoxText As String = "The item is in folder:" & vbLf & vbLf _
>                                                & DirectCast(mailItem.Parent, Outlook.Folder).FolderPath
>                 MsgBox(messageBoxText, 0, "In which folder?")
>
>             Case "FolderGoto"
>                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current: " & TryCast(myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name, String) _
>                                                                & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)  ' yields <1>
>                 ' Change the current folder:
>                 myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = DirectCast(mailItem.Parent, Outlook.Folder)
>                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Current: " & TryCast(myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name, String) _
>                                                                & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)  ' yields <0>
>                 System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()            ' needed, otherwise the mailItem will not be selectable
>
>                 ' Additionally, set the initial mailItem as selected:
>                 ' But this doesn't work for unknown reasons.
>                 ' .AddToSelection() does not work for unknown reasons.
>                 If myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(mailItem) Then
>                     ' https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aedcbda9-5304-4969-82ac-dbd41e0879b0/select-item-in-activeexplorer?forum=outlookdev
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selectable!")
>
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Adding0: " & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)  ' <0> is OK
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CStr("Item: " & mailItem.Subject))                       ' verify, that the element is the desired one
>                     myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem)                                           ' This FAILS !
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Adding1: " & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)  ' should be <1> but is still <0> :-(
>                     System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()                                                 ' thought in vain that this would help
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Adding2: " & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)  ' should be <1> but is still <0> :-(
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Which Folder?    = " & myOutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name)
>                 Else
>                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Not selectable!")
>                 End If
>         End Select
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Nobody any idea?

Comment: I know, you use VB.net and not VBA, but maybe Microsoft's hints on this page may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.addtoselection